# Calculate the Consecutive occurance of a number

Tags: perl

Hi I have an input say "11234555611". I want to find out how many consecutive occurrences are there in the list. For example: 11, 555. I came up with

```
$val="11234555611";
# Splitting the numbers and putting in an array @strings.
my %count;

foreach my $str (@strings) {
 $count{$str}++;
}
```

This will give number of occruances of each number. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get the desired result? An error message? Incorrect output?  Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].  StackOverflow is not a tutorial or code-writing site. You are expected to put some effort into solving the actual problem, and then explain what you have done and what isn't working.

Comment: You can use a standard C-style (probably not the official name) `for` loop and just check if the previous character is equal to the current one.

Comment: @JimGarrison "This will give number of occruances of each number." This doesn't actually solve the required task. It's just a start.

Comment: What output do you want?

Answer (score -1):

Need a variable `$run` to keep track of how many consecutive characters we've seen:

```
my $val="11234555611";
my %count;
my $last_char = '';
my $run = 0;

foreach my $char (split //, $val) {
    if ($last_char == $char) {
        $run++;
    } else {
        $run = 1;
    }

    if ($run > $count{$char}) {
        $count{$char} = $run;
    }
    $last_char = $char;
}
```